# Sending IP Data to Server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-deployment

So I am making a web page, and one of the functions I want is to be able to store global IPs into a text file. I am a NOOB as far as this web development is concerned (Hardware dude).

So far I have on the client side-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>IP Grab</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A privileged app stub">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="prefetch" type="application/l10n" href="data/locales.ini" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/l10n.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <!-- Find Global IP Address -->
 <script type="application/javascript">
   function getIP(json) {
   document.write("My public IP address is: ", json.ip);
 }
 </script>
 <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
 
 <!-- Send Data to Server -->
 <script>
 jQuery.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "get.php",
  data: json.ip
 })
 </script>
 
 
    </body>
</html>
```

On the server side-

```html
<?php
data = $_POST['text'];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('ips.txt', $data);
>
```

I KNOW the php portion is VERY wrong... can someone point me in the right direction? I'm having a heard time finding a good tut.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know PHP, but on the JS side you should move the `jQuery.ajax()` call to inside the `getIP()` function, because you are trying to use the `json` variable that is local to the `getIP()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the client ip is easy in PHP .

```
$your_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

for more info you can visit PHP's official website http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

on a side note , you should read about http request and response cycle .